# why is firebase serve throwing error but not firebase deploy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase. I tried connecting firestore and cloud functions(Node JS).

I tried running `firebase serve`

but it showed an error saying there's a problem with unable to load the default credential in gcloud.

I already tried `firebase deploy` which works completely fine. It shows error only when I run locally.

Do I need to create an account in google cloud too and link my app to it?

Here's the full output error:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "getScreamDet"
>  Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
>      at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/Users/vigneshwar/Desktop/rsocialapp-backend/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to use `firebase-admin` package.
As for the latest firebase-admin, you **cannot** init with default credential like this.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

You would need to use a serviceAccount credential. Go to Firebase Project Settings > Service Accounts > FirebaseAdminSdk. Copy the code for initialization.

You would end up with something similar to this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "xxxxx"
});
```